# Opening of a cover letter

Tags: letter, openings, introduction, phrasing, cover-letter

I am currently writing a cover letter (for a job application) and after a long 'struggle' with the opening paragraph, I've decided to start it by briefly presenting myself and then continuing with

"The reason for which I am writing /*to you* ???/ is to express my interest in..."

I've already gone through so many other variants that I'm no more able to assess the suitablity/acceptablity of a given phrase, thus I will be very thankful if someone shares their opinion of the above one?

As a supplementary inquiry, I'd also like to ask about the expression "writing *to you*". I wonder - is it actually neccesary to add "... *to you*" or that's self-explanatory?

Comment: Have placed this on hold for now, since it's off-topic as per the reasons above. Please feel free to [edit] and we'll consider reopening; for more about how this site works, you can view our site [tour].

Answer (score 2):

In business communication, as in most other communication, you want to be as concise as possible while still being effective.

Your sentence "The reason for which I am writing..." with or without the "to you" is unnecessarily convoluted.

Try "I am writing to express my interest..."

or even "I am interested in..."

Get to the point. I read a lot of cover letters at work, and I'm not looking for high word count, I'm looking for basic information.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. May I ask, though, isn't it a little irritating when every sentence starts with "I ..."?